# Observer doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, configuration

I tried a few iterations and for whatever reason I can't add cookies or even execute any code from my observer, as it's not giving anything even if my observer has dies in it. I have my module visible on the list and enabled, there are no exceptions in the exception.log.

This is my xml file where observer define

> app/code/local/MyProject/Cookie123/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyProject_Cookie123>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </MyProject_Cookie123>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Cookie123>
                <class>MyProject_Cookie123_Model</class>
            </Cookie123>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <MyProject_Cookie123>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>MyProject_Cookie123_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customerLogin</method>
                    </MyProject_Cookie123>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
            <customer_logout>
                <observers>
                    <MyProject_Cookie123>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>MyProject_Cookie123_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customerLogout</method>
                    </MyProject_Cookie123>
                </observers>
            </customer_logout>
            <controller_front_send_response_before>
                <observers>
                    <MyProject_Cookie123>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>MyProject_Cookie123_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>sendResponse</method>
                    </MyProject_Cookie123>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_send_response_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

This is my Observer file:-

> app/code/local/MyProject/Cookie123/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class MyProject_Cookie123_Model_Observer
{

    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('testing_auth', 1);
    }

    public function customerLogout($observer)
    {
        Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->delete('testing_auth');
    }

    public function sendResponse($observer)
    {
        Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('test_123', 1);

        $cartItems = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsQty();
        if ($cartItems > 0) {
            Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('testing_cart', 1);
        } else {
            if (Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('testing_cart')) {
                Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->delete('testing_cart');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your config to following move your events to frontend tag & gave unique event ids:-
app/code/local/MyProject/Cookie123/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyProject_Cookie123>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </MyProject_Cookie123>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Cookie123>
                <class>MyProject_Cookie123_Model</class>
            </Cookie123>
        </models>

    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <myproject_cookie123_customerlogin>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>MyProject_Cookie123_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customerLogin</method>
                    </myproject_cookie123_customerlogin>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
            <customer_logout>
                <observers>
                    <myproject_cookie123_customerlogout>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>MyProject_Cookie123_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customerLogout</method>
                    </myproject_cookie123_customerlogout>
                </observers>
            </customer_logout>
            <controller_front_send_response_before>
                <observers>
                    <myproject_cookie123_sendresponse>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>MyProject_Cookie123_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>sendResponse</method>
                    </myproject_cookie123_sendresponse>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_send_response_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```